# How to shoe log message on performing find query in mongodb using mongod shell?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongo-shell, mlab

I was reading this article of mongodb on [Indexing and Performance](http://docs.mlab.com/indexing/) .
In this when they are performing any find query like `db.names.find( {"name": "Arya"} ).sort( {"year": 1} )`
They are showing some log messages which gives details about query. I dont know how how is the log message is printed , I tried to connect my mondodb free sandbox database from mongo shell. On executing the find query its prints the result but no log message . [Pls see here what I mean by log message.](http://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#comparing-log-lines)

Plesae help me how to see log message. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: The log message you are talking about shows up in the server logs not on the mongo shell. As such you can run `.explain` on find query to see the the index information. More info here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db-collection-explain

Comment: @Veeram Just to inform my server is in heroku and I am using Node js server. I did one find query but when i saw logs in server using :heroku logs it didnt show any such log message.